# get skype for business presence status programmatically

Tags: python, skype-for-business

I need to read the current presence status from Skype for Business (16.5.185) on OSX Sierra. Is there some way to read this locally on my laptop with any programming language, like python?

I think we use office365 and I don't have any control over the server or its settings, so I really would like to be able to find this information locally

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [UCWA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/developingucwaapplicationsforsfbonline) and then do something like (more infos [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/getpresencedataofacontact)):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 852
Date: Thu, 18 Jan 2013 00:04:19 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-MS-Server-Fqdn: W15-LYNC-SE1.contoso.com
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

{
"availability":"Offline",
"deviceType":"Unknown",
"lastActive":"\/Date(1358827096000)\/",
"_links":{
"self":{"href":"/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/101/people/sarad@contoso.com/presence"}
},
"rel":"contactPresence"
}
```

That should be possible via python.

If UCWA will not work for you you need to involve the Skype for Business client API (more infos [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/)).

*P.S. Keep noted that an Administrator can remove the LastActive attribute (so the time how long a user is e.g. away isn´t calculated) as explained [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2684128/how-to-remove-the-lastactive-attribute-from-the-aggregation-state-category-in-lync-server-2010,-lync-server-2013,-skype-for-business-server-2015,-and-skype-for-business-online).*

Comment: I've tried getting an oAuth token, but the examples are only partial. I did find the SfB logs and see calls going to https://webpooldm21a07.infra.lync.com/ucwa/v1/, but I'm not sure where to send the request for an oAuth token.

Comment: The link you provide when mentioning the client API doesn't appear to give any details about the client API.

Comment: Try the following: https://webdir1e.online.lync.com/WebTicket/oauthtoken

Comment: Neither of those URLs work for obtaining an oauth token.

Comment: https://markeev.com/posts/skype4b/ or https://ucwa.skype.com/documentation/gettingstarted-authentication give some more information, maybe it will help